# The loop has no output?

Tags: java

The code below has no output when I run it, I think somehow it is infinite loop? How to fix it?

Write a method named getEvenDigitSum with one parameter of type int called number.

The method should return the sum of the even digits within the number.

If the number is negative, the method should return -1 to indicate an invalid value.

EXAMPLE INPUT/OUTPUT:

- getEvenDigitSum(123456789); → should return 20 since 2 + 4 + 6 + 8 = 20
- getEvenDigitSum(252); → should return 4 since 2 + 2 = 4
- getEvenDigitSum(-22); → should return -1 since the number is negative

```
public class getEvenDigitSum {
    public static int getEvenDigitSum(int number) {

        int sum = 0;
        int lastDigit=0;
        if (number < 0) {
            return -1;
        }
            while (number >0) {
                lastDigit = number % 10;
                if (number % 2 == 0)
                {
                    sum += lastDigit;
                    number = number / 10;

                }
                
            }
    return sum;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `return String.valueOf(number).chars().map(c -> c - '0').filter(n -> n % 2 == 0).sum();`

Comment: Step through your code with the debugger and you will soon see what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
while (number >0) {
        lastDigit = number % 10;
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum += lastDigit;
            number = number / 10;

        }

}
```

OK, and what happens if the number isn't even? You didn't make an else/else if statement after; if your number is odd, it stays the same, the loop is infinite, and hence your code does nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Your condition only handles even digits, but think about what happens when you get a number that contains odd digit, like 1221 for example.

Try adding the missing else statement:

```
while (number >0) {
    lastDigit = number % 10;
        if (number % 2 == 0)
        {
            sum += lastDigit;
            number = number / 10;
        }
        else {
          // Deal with odd digit, leaving for you to implement 
        {
}
```

General tip: The best way to find errors in your code is to write tests and debug your code.

These are two skills every developer should poses and practice regularly